# How to expose @GetMapping @RequestBody with swagger and openapi?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, swagger, openapi

The following would be valid for a `@PostMapping`. But spring also supported wrapping `@GetMapping` parameters in a bean object.

Question: how can I expose the bean for a get-mapping endpoint with `openapi` `swagger` v3 annotations?

```
@RestController
public class PersonController {
   @GetMapping
   public Person get(@RequestBody(content = @Content(
            schema = @Schema(implementation = PersonDto.class)))  
        PersonDto req) {

   }
}
```